# [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: java, sql, sql-update, ms-access-2013

Need help with this update query on JAVA, just started learning this but having problems

Getting following error upon execution

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing
>   operator) in query expression 'B.AWHERE ID =4'.

and data is not updating in MS Access database file

```
public void update(Student s)
    {
        int w = Integer.parseInt(s.getID());

        String query = "UPDATE Student SET ID =" + w + "," + "FirstName =" + s.getFirstName() + "," + "LastName =" + s.getLastName() + "," + "Address =" + s.getAddress() + "," + "Gender =" + s.getGender() + "," + "DOB =" + s.getDOB() + "," + "Degree =" + s.getDegree() + "WHERE ID =" + w;

        try
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem in Query");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `UPDATE` statement to be like below

```
String query = "UPDATE Student SET "FirstName = '" + s.getFirstName() + 
"'," + "LastName = '" + s.getLastName() + 
"'," + "Address = '" + s.getAddress() + 
"'," + "Gender = '" + s.getGender() + 
"'," + "DOB = '" + s.getDOB() + 
"'," + "Degree = '" + s.getDegree() + 
"' WHERE ID = " + w;
```

But your query won't make much sense cause, you are setting `ID = w` and also checking `WHERE ID = w`

Comment: With this I am getting the following error
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 6.
I have also tried to leave out the SET ID part from your code but still same error
like this: "UPDATE Student SET FirstName =" + s.getFirstName() + "," + "LastName =" + s.getLastName() + "," + "Address =" + s.getAddress() + "," + "Gender =" + s.getGender() + "," + "DOB =" + s.getDOB() + "," + "Degree =" + s.getDegree() + " WHERE ID =" + w;

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from database into JFrame Fields (Text, Radia etc), and from there I am trying to update fields in the table based on the changes in the Jframe.

The data from JFrame gets stored in the Student object that calls this function so the changes made in JFrame can be saved including the ID if changed

Comment: @DanishAli, add a space in where condition like `s.getDegree() + "  WHERE ID =" + w;`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul, this worked perfect.

String query = "UPDATE Student SET FirstName = '" + s.getFirstName() + "'," + "LastName = '" + s.getLastName() + "'," + "Address = '" + s.getAddress() + "'," + "Gender = '" + s.getGender() + "'," + "DOB = '" + s.getDOB() + "'," + "Degree = '" + s.getDegree() + "' WHERE ID = " + w;

Comment: @DanishAli, that's great. Consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button under voting button.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing spaces and apostrophes for string values in your whole query E.g.

```
 "Degree =" + s.getDegree() + "WHERE ID ="
```

is being evaluated to
     "Degree =BAWHERE ID ="

which is invalid syntax.

EDIT: I can only guess that your `Student` object returns strings in the getter methods so try this.

```
String query = "UPDATE Student SET ID =" + w + ","
    + "FirstName =\"" + s.getFirstName() + "\","
    + "LastName =\"" + s.getLastName() + "\","
    + "Address =\"" + s.getAddress() + "\","
    + "Gender =\"" + s.getGender() + "\","
    + "DOB =\"" + s.getDOB() + "\","
    + "Degree =\"" + s.getDegree() + "\" "
    + "WHERE ID =" + w;
```

Comment: So what the correct syntax be like, because if I try to put spaces and apostrophes I get Syntax error
for example
String query = "UPDATE Student SET ID = " + 'w' + " , " + "FirstName = " + 'a' + " , " + "LastName = " + 'b' + " , " + "Address = " + 'c' + " , " + "Gender = " + 'd' + " , " + "DOB = " + 'f' + " , " + "Degree = " + 'g' + "WHERE ID = " + w;

Comment: I am getting the following error now with the above code
[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in string in query expression 'B.A" WHERE ID =4'.
Yes getters setters are of string type

Comment: Ok, forget about the java for now. What query are you expecting to run against the database with all the values filled in?

Comment: There is an existing database of student in MS Access file, upon searching a particular ID I am shown the details of the student on the JFrame in their relevent fields. If I make any changes in those fields I want  those changes to be updated in the Access database including the ID if changed

Comment: So far insert data and retrieving the data both operations are working great, just need to update or replace the existing data row in the table (matching ID) with new data if changed

Comment: Log the query before it gets executed and put it here for us to see.